# PHP: Class 'xmlrpc_client' not found

Tags: php, apache, xml-rpc

I'm trying to connect to another website with XML RPC, but PHP says it can't find the xmlrpc_client class.

I have..

- checked my php.ini (xmlrpc is activated)
- checked my phpinfo() (xmlrpc is shown, xmlrpc-epi v. 0.51)
- restarted Apache
- restarted my PC (working on localhost)

..but still no xmlrpc_client class.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the phpinfo() if it uses the php.ini you assume.

Answer (score 0):

`ext/xmlrpc` does not provide a class `xmlrpc_client` but only a few lower level functions to deal with XML/RPC.

If you don’t like dealing with `ext/xmlrpc`directly, there are various clients abstracting the nitty gritty details. E.g. Zend Framework’s `Zend\XmlRpc` or my own pet project [`fxmlrpc`](https://github.com/lstrojny/fxmlrpc).

Have a look at http://en.php.net/xmlrpc for documentation about `ext/xmlrpc`